# Change github user / private key

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm trying to ssh into github using a different private key than my original one.  It seems like the `ssh` request is somehow cached, because no matter what I do when I call `ssh -T git@github.com`, it says

> Hi [wrong-user] You've successfully authenticated...

I've tried doing a variety of things:

- Removing `github.user` and `user.email` from my `.gitconfig`
- Removing my `id_rsa` completely
- Using `ssh -i` with different identity files including an *invalid* identity file
- Updating my `.ssh/config` with

> 

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile /path/to/private/key/for/right-user
```

No matter what it seems like I always get a response from github logging in as the wrong user.

Is there something else I can do to tell github to use a different user / private key to authenticate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your cached ssh keys with `ssh-add -l`.

You can delete all cached keys with `ssh-add -D`.